# How to define in testbench 2 different entity work selected by a variable

Tags: vhdl

Is there a way to define in a TestBench file, 2 different entity.work (with port map) and select one of these 2 by a variable or by another way ?
If I write this:

```
ENTITY_A_GEN : if I USE_ENTITY_A = true generate 
    entity work.entity_A 
        generic map (n => n) 
        port map ( 
                    sig1 => sig1, 
                    ....etc 
                  );
end generate ENTITY_A_GEN;
```

It's giving me an error "ERROR: Syntax error near entity"

Comment: Your specific programming problem isn't clear. ([A minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) only has to have one port in a port clause to meet your criteria. A generic constant which most VHDL implementations will allow to have a value provided to the simulator, used to specify which architecture or which entity is used through a conditional generate statement expressing both instantiations. You could likewise have two different configuration declarations specifying different entities or architectures.)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constant in the architecture as a boolean, then use a generate statement:

```
--In arch section
constant USE_ENTITY_A : boolean := true;


--In code body
ENTITY_A_GEN : if USE_ENTITY_A = true generate

   --Code to instantiate Entity A

end generate ENTITY_A_GEN;



ENTITY_B_GEN : if USE_ENTITY_A = false generate

   --Code to instantiate Entity B

end generate ENTITY_B_GEN;
```

Comment: Note that VHDL 2008 supports the `else generate` clause.

Comment: If I write the following: 
ENTITY_A_GEN : if I USE_ENTITY_A = true generate 
    entity work.entity_A
      generic map (n => n)
      port map (
        sig1  => sig1, 
        ....etc 
end generate ENTITY_A_GEN;  

It's giving me an error "ERROR: Syntax error near entity"

Comment: A case of a wavy handed question followed by a wavy handed answer.  Provide a [mcve]. Note the code snippet appended to the question has an extraneous I : ENTITY_A_GEN : if I USE_ENTITY_A = true generate, neither of the constants are declared or defined, the entity instantiation requires a label and must be found in a library. The question isn't of sufficient quality to answer nor is the answer verifiable as a result. (And that doesn't preclude someone from editing the question and providing a verifiable answer).

Comment: In my example, the constant is declared in the architecture of course. Is the label of the entity must be known in the library (even if I do not entering in this part of code) ? Is the tool is checking the label of the entity  in library, even if I'm not using it ?

Comment: @Gilles06 I see you edited your question to try and include my generate statement. However, you have an extra character listed: "if USE_ENTITY_A = true" versus "if I USE_ENTITY_A = true"

Comment: Yes, you're right. The right way should be "if USE_ENTITY_A = true". But even that it's not working and I still have an error.

Comment: If you ignore the extra "I" character, I don't see any problems in the code you posted, but you only posted a little bit. Can you post more? I think the #1 "typical" error I've seen is that there should be no comma on the final port assignment in the instantiation.